# Why margin-top different for chrome and safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

1. Chrome and safari both supports `webkit`. then why `margin-top` different for chrome and safari?
2. What is the solution on that? I dont want to try `padding-top`..because of some reason.

this is my demo code for *responsive design*.

```
<div id='demo'></div>

#demo{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:22%;
    width:10%;
    border:1px black solid;
    height:5%;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/hcracnsb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Anwer**

1. I didn't got my first question's answer.

but i got my 2nd question's  answer.

```
    <div class='test'>
       <div id='demo'></div>
   </div>

#demo{
    position:absolute;
    width:10%;
    border:1px black solid;
    height:5%;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
.test{
    position:relative;
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
}
```

Added `position:relative` to parent div and instead of `margin-top` i used

```
bottom:0;  right:0;
```